# Question about the graphs of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the point $(2,3)$ is on the graph of $f$, then what can we say about $f(2)$?

I have an idea of what this question is asking me but nothing more. I suspect that it has something to do with linear vs constant functions.

No direct answer please.

Comment: It has nothing to do with linear vs constant functions. It is simply testing your understanding of a couple of basic concepts (Cartesian coordinates, graph of a function). PS: What does "No direct answer please" mean?

Comment: @TonyK, I agree with you !!

Comment: @TonyK I believe he means for us to not just say $f(2)=\ldots$ without giving an explanation.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I would rather get an explanation that helps me find the correct answer by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point $(2,3)$ means that the function passes the point where $x=2$ & $y=3$. $f(2)$ is the value of $y$ at $x=2$. Note that for a specific $x$, there is only one $y$.

Comment: Therefore $(2,3)$ is $f(2)$ plotted on the graph and $f(2) = 3$?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Indeed.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The graph of a function $f$ plots $x$ on the $x$-axis against $f(x)$ on the $y$-axis -  which means that every point on the graph is of the form $(x, f(x))$.